# How can an aircraft door be modified to open in flight at cruising altitudes?

Tags: cabin-pressure, doors

Just do a Google search for opening an airliner door in midair will spring up a dozen sites of why this is nearly impossible, if not possible.

> And the difference between the inside of the plane and the outside can be huge. Which is exactly where the doors come in. Inside the cabin, 8 pounds of pressure push against every square inch of surface area. The typical passenger door is about 6 feet tall by 3 1/2 feet wide. So we're looking at more than 24,000 pounds of pressure bearing down on that exit.

Source: [Why it's physically impossible to open an airplane door mid-flight](https://www.businessinsider.com/why-plane-doors-cant-open-mid-flight-2020-2)

Another article from WP:

[No, unruly passenger: You can’t physically open a plane door midflight](https://www.washingtonpost.com/travel/2022/02/16/open-plane-door-flight-unruly-passenger/)

However, it seems the recently retired  NASA telescope carrying Boeing 747 (N747NA) could open a telescope POD while the plane is in midair:

[image: SOFIA]

Source: [NASA bids farewell to SOFIA: the unique Boeing 747SP aircraft modified to carry a reflecting telescope made its last flight](https://theaviationgeekclub.com/nasa-bids-farewell-to-sofia-the-unique-boeing-747sp-aircraft-modified-to-carry-a-reflecting-telescope-made-its-last-flight/)

So mean it's possible to open a door or hatch of an airliner in flight?

Comment: The door and aircraft would have to be specifically designed to do that. Typical aircraft and doors are not.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It is not quite clear what you are asking about. Are you asking whether it is possible to open a normal airliner door, which is explicitly and specifically designed to be impossible to open during flight? Or are you asking whether it is possible to spend millions of dollars to modify an airliner and design and build a special door that is explicitly and specifically designed and built to be opened in flight?

Comment: Also, you posted a photo of an airliner with its door open in flight, so doesn't that photo already answer the question?

Comment: The B747 is either being operated unpressurized or there is a bulkhead between the section of the airplane with the telescope and open door and the remainder of the airplane beyond the bulkhead is pressurized.

Comment: [Here](https://www.dsi.uni-stuttgart.de/en/public/observatory/) is a good description of how the SOFIA telescope is installed: "The telescope is located in the rear of the fuselage, which has a sealable opening. The passenger cabin and the telescope cavity are separated by a pressure bulkhead. During observations, the instruments and the scientists are in the passenger cabin and the telescope - when the hatch is open - is exposed to the conditions that exist outside the airplane."

Comment: Note on SOFIA: if you look the photos or the documentation, you see that the door is much larger then normal, but so it needs a lot of internal reinforcements: there is a lot of extra steel inside the aircraft to avoid deformations (both for pressurization and for the larger door). Some sky diving aircraft can do it (but usually they are not used on such high altitudes, which you didn't really specify).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question, (like so many others) is : “It depends”.

Most airliner doors could be opened in flight, but ONLY if the aircraft is first depressurized.

Some other designs can be opened, even if pressurized, but usually only due to a mechanical failure.

There have been a few examples over the years of pressurized doors
opening inadvertently.

Here is one example:  [Time Air F28 main cabin door opens in flight](https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19920730-1)

[image]

Here is another F28 example: [Airlines of Western Australia F28 main cabin door opens in flight](https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/209162)

[image]
[image]

Comment: "usually only due to a mechanical failure" I take that to mean unlocked (disarmed) from the pilot's controls. But how does that account for the pressurisation differences of 20kpa bearing down on the door?

Comment: Pilots have no control over the operation of entry doors in the flight deck. Some designs can be accidentally opened, even when pressurized.  It depends on the design, and it depends on the failure.

Comment: @Nederealm i.e. some designs have to be opened inwards, which is impossible due to the 1-tonne-per-square-meter pressurization force pushing out. Some designs open outwards, and have mechanical locking mechanisms that stop them opening when pressurized, but sometimes the locking mechanisms break. (See the DC-10 cargo bay door!)